# DB2 to Netezza Migration

Tags: db2, netezza

I have  one query in DB2 which has mentioned below.
What would be the syntax for the same in NETEZZA?

select distinct acct_num from GTD_demo_dim where ACCT_NUM fetch first 1 rows only);

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think your statement is valid.

> `select distinct acct_num from GTD_demo_dim where ACCT_NUM fetch first 1 rows only);`

The `where` clause needs to be finished and you've used a closing parenthesis without an opening one.

`fetch first` is common (standard?) ODBC syntax, so it's very likely that this will work. However, the usual way to do this in netezza is using a limit. All that said, this is how I'd query and expect the intended result (omitting your `where` since I can't infer the intent):

```
select distinct acct_num from gtd_demo_dim limit 1;
```